# Pythonic way to open a file and yield its contents inside a class without using the class constructor

Tags: python

### Context

I am trying to create a pretty generic class that reads a csv file and has a method that yields each of its rows (I will process each row before yielding it but I am not including that part here to get to the simplest possible example here).

### My question

I can think of a solution that will probably work but doesn't feel very elegant. Can you point me to a more pythonic pattern to solve this?

The only restriction is that **I cannot use the constructor to open the file**. That is  because these classes will be used by external tools and need to comply with the right protocols so the file is not available for the constructor.

### The "probably not optimal" solution I can think of

```python
import petl as etl

class Reader():
    data = None
    initialized = False    

    def read_file(self,file):
        if not self.initialized:
            self.data = etl.fromcsv(file_name)
            self.initialized = True

    def rows(self):
        for row in self.data.namedtuples():
            yield row
```

Comment: Is it reasonable for your use case to do a just-in-time approach, where `read_file` or the like is triggered the first time something like `rows` is called?

Comment: `read_file` should probably just be `__init__`, dispensing with the `initialized` attribute. It appears that `etl.fromcsv` doesn't do much more than open the file and act as an iterator itself. You could also define `rows` as simply `yield from self.data.namedtuples()`.

Comment: @AndrewAllaire Yes, triggering read_file the first time `rows` is called will be perfect. I am just not sure how to avoid it being called every time `rows` is called. How would you go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you need data and initialized to be object data rather than class data. Also they should be probably marked as private-ish by leading underscore.

Here is how I would approach it:

```
class Reader():

    def __init__(self, file):
        self._file = file
        self._initialized = False
        self._data = None


    def read_file(self):
        if not self._initialized:
            self._data = etl.fromcsv(self._file)
            self._initialized = True

    def rows(self):
        self.read_file()
        for row in self.data.namedtuples():
            yield row
```

Note that read_files is called when rows is just in case it wasn't before (just in time approach if not already called).

Also it may be considered pythonic to have an iteration method that does what rows() does, just named `__iter__()` instead of `rows()`.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems to me like calling read_file() every time row is called is not ideal. Wouldn't it be better to put the `if` statement around the function call instead?

Comment: In this instance, would `self.read_file()` be called only the first time or once for every row? If it is only called the first time, this solution is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the pointer on object data vs class data, a much better solution and I was totally missing it

Comment: The `read_file()` is called often yes, and all the time except the first time it does not get past the `if not self._initialized` part so avoids the cost of reading the file again. It may or may be slightly more efficient to put the `if not self._initialized` in the `rows` function such that read_file is not called at all instead of calling read_file and having it return right away. But I like having the guard in the initialization functions/methods themselves so that I do not forget to put the guard in all the places I use them.